# Which image extension is better for both quality and performance(speed)?

Tags: html, css, image, performance, image-processing

I have an html website (pure HTMl , CSS , JS) , and I'm using some images (main images - some icons), for the main images (The images at the top of each page that covers all the width) each is about 3000 x 1264 .

For example an image called "**cat**" , if I'm using "**png**" extension the size will be about **2MB** , and if I'm using "**jpg**" the size would be about **700KB** , For performance and speed I would choose "jpg" because it's about less than the half of "png" , but I'm afraid that this may affect images quality .

So I'm wondering what is the best extension to use that wouldn't affect both performance and images quality ? **It doesn't have to be "png" or "jpg"**

Answer (score 0):

Perfect ext for website is **`.svg`** for icons **`.webp`** for images (chrome only) to cut load time. For cross browser images use **`.jpg`** instead. But you need software to resize the image to make it smaller such as photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

Depends. JPG is generally a good compromise for photos, PNGs for graphic elements that need transparency, for example.

In general, a 2MB image for a web page is too much. You have to compromise between quality and weight and use compression tools such as [ShortPixel](https://shortpixel.com/free-sign-up-referrer/referrer/109959).

Answer (score 0):

They both have their uses.

JPEG

JPGs have become the de facto standard image of the internet because they can be compressed so much. A typical JPG can be compressed at a ratio of anywhere from 2:1 to as high as 100:1, depending on your settings. Particularly back in the days of dial-up internet, JPGs were the only viable way to send image information.

However, because of the lossy nature of JPG, it is not an ideal way to store art files. Even the highest quality setting for JPG is compressed, and will change the look of your image, if only slightly. JPG is also not an ideal medium for typography, crisp lines, or even photographs with sharp edges, as they are often blurred or smeared out by anti-aliasing. What is potentially worse, is that this loss can accumulate-saving multiple versions of artwork can cause degradation with every save. Even so, it is common to see these things saved as JPG, simply because the filetype is so ubiquitous.

PNG

PNG supports 8-bit color like GIF, but also supports 24-bit color RGB, like JPG does. They are also non-lossy files, compressing photographic images without degrading image quality. PNG tends to be the biggest of the three filetypes and isn't supported by some (usually older) browsers.

In addition to being an excellent format for transparency, the non-lossy nature of 24-bit PNG is ideal for screenshot software, allowing pixel for pixel reproduction of your desktop environment.